# Large white box with the word {{query}} appearing in my WebView

Tags: android, angularjs, android-webview

I created an unofficial app for the Miscers over at bodybuilding.com. They recently updated their website and ever since I'm getting this huge white box that comes up only after the page finishes loading. There's no error, it doesn't occur on the older black theme, doesn't occur on the mobile site in a browser and it doesn't occur on a basic WebView. I was wondering if someone could shed some light on what's going on with the {{query}} message. It's impossible to search for due to the brackets being stripped from every search field.

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHNOT.png

Comment: I'm guessing it has something to do with AngularJS, as that's the syntax for a directive.  Do you have Javascript enabled?

Comment: Yes: miscWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

Comment: Do you see any Javascript error in your LogCat?

Comment: No JavaScript errors. However enabling it is what's causing the white box to appear. I confirmed this by making an app with just a webview and just enabling JavaScript is what broke the site in the WebView. It seems to be a drop-down linked to the search bar that isn't loading properly.

Comment: The solution to this problem was to simply disable JavaScript on the WebView. Some script on their site is just not behaving properly in the WebView. Did some remote debugging on chrome and removed the blank box to find the "Top Searches" box underneath it. My guess is that they are using AngularJS to populate it and it's failing. http://i.imgur.com/ApNiIUO.png